# Set baseline programmatically in project server

Tags: csom, ms-project

How I can set the baseline programmatic-ally in Microsoft project server? 
Are there any blogs about this?

Answer (score 1):

providing the version you are using or any useful details can help you to explain your question properly.

but in general you cannot set baselines using PSI nor CSOM, according to MSDN post here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767706.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#pj14_WhatPSIDoes_DoesNotDo

> Actions that require Project Professional: The following list are
>   things that neither the PSI nor the CSOM can do. . . . Baselines and
>   earned value
>
> - Saving a baseline or editing baseline data.
> - Setting a progress date.
> - Calculating variance and earned value.